# Como alterar as propriedades de um Form estando dentro de um UserControl que não está na Form? C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, formulário, usercontrol

No meu código eu estou dentro de um UserControl que não está dentro do Form e gostaria de alterar as propriedades do meu Form através desse UserControl. Exemplo do meu código:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Botão dentro do UserControl
{
  Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
  frm1.label.Text = "Changed";
}
```

Coloquei o componente Label que está na Form1 como Public, instanciei a Form1 dentro do meu UserControl e acessei o componente, trocando o seu texto, porém eu clico e não acontece alteração nenhuma na Form1, então a minha dúvida é, como eu posso alterar as propriedades de um Form através de um UserControl que não está nessa Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa da instância do próprio `Form1` (por exemplo, passada por parâmetro para o usercontrol), uma instanciada criada dentro do seu UserControl é um objecto diferente do outro já criado.

Outra opção seria usar a propriedade `OpenForms`:

```
Form1 frm1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
frm1.label.Text = "Changed";
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, thanks